# How can I create a generic type for a dynamic generated object created from an array

Tags: typescript, generics, string-literals, typescript-generics

I'm trying to generate a type definition for a function that generates an object from an array of props, but I'm having problems with this.

The problem is that in `{ [K in T]: boolean }`, I'm not being able to iterate over the type T.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```js
const createObject = <T extends string[]>(props: T): { [K in T]: boolean } => {
  return props.reduce((acc: any, prop: string) => {
    acc[prop] = true
    return acc
  }, {})
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

just a little bit workaround... here you are

```
const createObject = <T extends string>(props: T[]): {[K in T]: boolean} => {
  return props.reduce((acc: any, prop: string) => {
    acc[prop] = true;
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

const testObj = createObject(['one', 'two']);
const one = testObj.one;
const two = testObj.two;
const three = testObj.three; // ERROR
```